# Activiti hello world test

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, activiti, bpmn

I am trying to make a simple Hello world application using Activiti 5.13 BPMN.  I made a dynamic web application project in eclipse and added my hello_world.bpmn diagram to the root folder and my test.java and activiti.cfg.xml files to the src folder.  The application is just suppose to print "Hello, world" to the console, but I cannot seem to get it to do this.  Below if all the files that I am using to run the application, also I am using a PostgreSQL database (I created all the necessary tables)

My hello_world.bpmn file is as following:

start event - > user script (groovy) - > end event

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startProcess" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <scriptTask id="scriptProcess" name="Hello world" scriptFormat="groovy" activiti:autoStoreVariables="true">
      <script>System.out.println("Hello, world this is the activiti process")</script>
    </scriptTask>
    <endEvent id="endProcess" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startProcess" targetRef="scriptProcess"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="scriptProcess" targetRef="endProcess"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_myProcess">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="myProcess" id="BPMNPlane_myProcess">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startProcess" id="BPMNShape_startProcess">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="110.0" y="220.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="scriptProcess" id="BPMNShape_scriptProcess">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="210.0" y="210.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endProcess" id="BPMNShape_endProcess">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="390.0" y="220.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="145.0" y="237.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="210.0" y="237.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="315.0" y="237.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="390.0" y="237.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

My activiti.cfg.xml file is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans ;
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
 <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">
 <!-- Database configurations  -->
 <property name="databaseType" value="postgres" />
 <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
 <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
 <property name="jdbcUsername" value="user1234" />
 <property name="jdbcPassword" value="password1234" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

My test.java file is as following:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();

        RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
        RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
        TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
        ManagementService managementService = processEngine.getManagementService();
        IdentityService identityService = processEngine.getIdentityService();
        HistoryService historyService = processEngine.getHistoryService();
        FormService formService = processEngine.getFormService();

        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess");


        System.out.println("PRINT THIS MESSAGE");
    }
}
```

When I run the application on my tomcat server I get the following results:

```
    11:34:14,359 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
11:34:14,578 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 21 11:34:14 CDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
11:34:14,750 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
11:34:14,890 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/activiti-standalone-context.xml]
11:34:14,953 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/activiti-ui-context.xml]
11:34:15,328 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer  - Loading properties file from class path resource [db.properties]
11:34:15,343 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer  - Loading properties file from class path resource [ui.properties]
11:34:15,437 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@caa278: defining beans [demoDataGenerator,dbProperties,dataSource,transactionManager,processEngineConfiguration,processEngine,repositoryService,runtimeService,taskService,historyService,managementService,identityService,activitiLoginHandler,activitiUiPropertyPlaceholder,navigatorManager,attachmentRendererManager,formPropertyRendererManager,variableRendererManager,componentFactories,processDefinitionFilterFactory,deploymentFilterFactory,navigationFragmentChangeListener,mainWindow,explorerApp,i18nManager,scopedTarget.messageSource,messageSource,notificationManager,viewManager,workflowDefinitionConversionFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
11:34:19,531 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl  - ProcessEngine default created
11:34:19,531 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobExecutor  - Starting up the JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
11:34:19,531 [Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnable  - JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
11:34:19,546 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator  - Initializing demo groups
11:34:19,765 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator  - Initializing demo users
11:34:19,921 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator  - Initializing demo process definitions
11:34:19,937 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator  - Initializing demo models
11:34:19,953 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator  - Initializing demo report data
11:34:19,953 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobExecutor  - Shutting down the JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
11:34:19,953 [Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnable  - JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] stopped job acquisition
11:34:20,281 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/VacationRequest.png
11:34:20,281 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/FixSystemFailureProcess.bpmn20.xml
11:34:20,484 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6109 ms
Aug 21, 2013 11:34:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 21, 2013 11:34:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 21, 2013 11:34:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15043 ms
11:34:21,250 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/FixSystemFailureProcess.png
11:34:21,250 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/VacationRequest.bpmn20.xml
11:34:21,421 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/createTimersProcess.bpmn20.xml
11:34:21,484 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/simple-approval.simpleApprovalProcess.png
11:34:21,484 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/reviewSalesLead.bpmn20.xml
11:34:21,593 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/reviewSalesLead.reviewSaledLead.png
11:34:21,593 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/Helpdesk.png
11:34:21,593 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/Helpdesk.bpmn20.xml
11:34:21,656 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/simple-approval.bpmn20.xml
11:34:36,953 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobExecutor  - Starting up the JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
11:34:36,953 [Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator  - Demo report data generated
11:34:36,953 [Thread-4] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnable  - JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
```

Comment: For future beginners this might help: http://codecramp.com/activiti-setup-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

What's here looks OK. Have you looked in the activiti explorer to make sure your process deployed properly? You can exercise your process in the explorer too. This serves as a sanity check before you start using it in your code.

That process name looks a little funny. Normally when you deploy a process to activiti via the explorer, it appends a version number to the process name like "myProcess:23". This extended name is what you use to instantiate the process.

Comment: Shouldn't it be printing "Hello, world" to the console?

Answer (score 1):

This code is completely wrong. To test your process look at [this](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#apiUnitTesting)  chapter of documentation or just use Activiti Explorer as Hethcox suggested. If you want to correct existing application read [process engine in a web application](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#apiProcessEngineInWebApp) chapter

Answer (score 1):

I have written a super detailed blog post on this, which starting from the setup, shows how to create not one but two fully working (although, simple) workflows.

You can check it out [here](http://codecramp.com/activiti-setup-eclipse/) and see if it helps.

The first example to print "Hello Activiti" should be what you are looking for.

Comment: In essence, this is a link-only answer; and thus of very very limited help to future readers - as links have that nasty habit of breaking. Thus: add at least a bit of explanation/summary.